# Expression of the conditional probability of the form $P( X \in A |\, Y \in B)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am interested in finding the conditional probability $P( X \in A |\, Y \in B)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are two (non-independent) continuous random variables. In my case, $X$ depends on $Y$, $A=[x_1,x_2]$ and  $B=[y_1,y_2]$.
To compute this probability, the Wikipedia article on Conditional Probability provides the following  [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Definition_with_.CF.83-algebra): $$P( X \in A |\, Y \in B)= \frac{ \int_{y \in B} \int_{x \in A} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy }{  \int_{y \in B} \int_{x \in \Omega} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy}. $$
I don't understand what is $\Omega$, and they don't provide its definition.
Any idea what does $\Omega$ represent ?

Another thing: Is the above formula equivalent to write: $P( X \in A |\, Y \in B)=\frac{1}{F_Y(y_2)-F_Y(y_1)}(F_{XY}(x_2,y_2)+F_{XY}(x_1,y_1)-F_{XY}(x_1,y_2)-F_{XY}(x_2,y_1))$ ?
Here $F$ denotes the CDF.

---

P.S. of @drhab: The link in this question will not show the wrong $\Omega$ but the correct $\mathbb R$. This because the Wikipedia page has been updatet after this question.

Comment: $\Omega$ is the whole of sample space. Regarding your second question, the answer is yes.

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic I think $\Omega$ is wrongly used here. If $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a random variable then in the exposed formula it must be replaced by $\mathbb R$. Note that the sets $A,B$ are subsets of $\mathbb R$. Not subsets of $\Omega$.

Comment: $f_{X,Y}$ denotes a density and is a function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ with special qualities. So its arguments  must be elements of $\mathbb R^2$. That asks for $x\in\mathbb R$, not $x\in\Omega$. You have traced on error on Wikipedia.

Comment: @drhab Yes, of course, I am afraid I was a little absent minded.

Comment: I have repaired the Wikipedia page by replacing $\Omega$ by $\mathbb R$. People that open the link might wonder: where is that $\Omega$ you are talking about in your question. To clarify I placed a small P.S. in your question.

Comment: So, if $X$ is defined over $[0, \infty)$, then we should replace $\Omega$  by $[0, \infty)$ ? Thank you.

Comment: @din Yes, replace $\Omega$ with the range of $X$; we all assumed $X: \Omega \to \mathbb R$.